# Magento 2 associate developer free practice test

Tags: magento2

Done anyone provide Magento 2 associate developer free practice test? 
Or 
 
Does anyone provide Magento 2 associate developer free study material? 
Which type of question asked in the exam? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Please check below mentioned Url, it's the best guideline to prepare for Associate Developer Exam, and they have attached study guide aswell.
https://www.sudhanshubajaj.com/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-preparation/

Answer (score 0):

Check out Examtask practice set for Associate Developer Exam preparation. They have covered the complete exam topics. Free and paid both plans are available.

https://examtask.com/certifications/magento/magento2-certified-associate-developer-practice-test/

Best of luck.